# Height of Peter Macon / Lt. Bortus

Tags: special-effects, the-orville, makeup

As can be seen from this picture,

[image]

Lt. Bortus is depicted as extremely tall compared to other member of the Orville crew.
Is this the natural build of Peter Macon, or is the appearance manipulated through prosthetics, lifts, and/or special effects?  (Which?)

Comment: ThePopMachine - That doesn't look extremely tall to me.  i have heard of historical human characters  who were much taller than that.  "Quite tall: would be more fitting.

Answer (score 3):

That appears to be his natural build, albeit wearing a padded jacket with foam shoulders. I've found multiple pictures of him alongside his fellow cast members

[image]

and directly alongside another actor, Geoffrey Kent whose [bio](http://www.maxtalent.com/actors/actor.cfm/Geoffrey-Kent/0/id/682) lists him as **6 foot and 2 inches** in height.

[image]

Based on the image in the show, I would imagine they've played with the lighting, put him in slightly lifted shoes and had him stand slightly farther forward in order to get him to appear to stand head and shoulders above his crewmates.

Comment: OK, good start, but the part "you are imagining" is kind of what the question is asking about...

Comment: @ThePopMachine - Well, for starters you can see that he's wearing padded shoulders.

Comment: Yeah, I was more thinking the height, but then I got a little more generic when I wrote 'build' in the text.

Comment: I'm not sure they're using any trickery beyond his padded shoulders and head-makeup. He's standing next to Scott Grimes in the question picture, and again in the cast picture o the answer here. In both cases it looks like the top of Grimes head lines right up with the middle of Macon's head.